# How can read grouped data from a TList<> in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tlist, delphi-xe3

In C# Linq would make this super-easy but I am new to using Lists in Delphi and I need some advice.

I have a list of objects stored as `TList<IMyInterface>` with each object essentially being a collection of data, e.g.

```
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4
```

I wish to create a new `TList<TList<IMyInterface>>` where the items in the list are grouped such as:

```
1, 1 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2 
3 
4, 4, 4
```

What would be the most effective way of doing this in Delphi XE3 (starter edition)?

Comment: I'd use a dictionary to collect the groups. Nothing remotely as slick as Linq in Delphi.

Comment: +1 for `TDictionary` of `TList<>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest would be a set of loops. Using the DeHL or Spring frameworks for Delphi might shorten your code a bit, but not much.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246378/copy-content-from-list1-to-list2-with-specific-criteria) about querying generic TList instances using conditions gives a hint on using the Collections from the Spring framework.

[My example](https://besharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/94898) uses `Integer` in stead of your interface type, but it should be easy to adapt.

Below are two methods for splitting, depending if you want each list to start on a changing value, or only for distinct values (like David said: long live `TDictionary<Key, Value>`)

I see the difference, I doubled your example:

```
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4
```

The first algorithm will return these:

```
1, 1
2, 2, 2, 2
3
4, 4, 4
1, 1
2, 2, 2, 2
3
4, 4, 4
```

The second these:

```
1, 1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
3, 3
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
```

Here is the example program; only printing requires nested loops.

```
program SplitListOfIntegersIntoSublists;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TIntegerList = TList<Integer>;
  TIntegerListList = TList<TIntegerList>;
  TMain = class(TObject)
  private
    class function AddNewIntegerList(IntegerListList: TIntegerListList): TIntegerList;
    class procedure AddValues(AllIntegers: TIntegerList);
    class procedure Fill_NewListForEachValueChange(const AllIntegers: TIntegerList; const IntegerListList: TIntegerListList);
    class procedure Fill_NewListForDistinctValues(const AllIntegers: TIntegerList; const IntegerListList: TIntegerListList);
    class procedure Free(const IntegerListList: TIntegerListList);
    class procedure Print(const IntegerList: TIntegerList); overload;
    class procedure Print(const IntegerListList: TIntegerListList); overload;
  public
    class procedure Run;
  end;

class function TMain.AddNewIntegerList(IntegerListList: TIntegerListList): TIntegerList;
begin
  Result := TIntegerList.Create;
  IntegerListList.Add(Result);
end;

class procedure TMain.AddValues(AllIntegers: TIntegerList);
begin
// 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4
  AllIntegers.Add(1);
  AllIntegers.Add(1);
  AllIntegers.Add(2);
  AllIntegers.Add(2);
  AllIntegers.Add(2);
  AllIntegers.Add(2);
  AllIntegers.Add(3);
  AllIntegers.Add(4);
  AllIntegers.Add(4);
  AllIntegers.Add(4);
end;

class procedure TMain.Fill_NewListForEachValueChange(const AllIntegers: TIntegerList; const IntegerListList: TIntegerListList);
var
  IntegerList: TIntegerList;
  Value: Integer;
begin
  for Value in AllIntegers do
  begin
    if (IntegerListList.Count = 0) or (Value <> IntegerList.First) then
      IntegerList := AddNewIntegerList(IntegerListList);
    IntegerList.Add(Value);
  end;
end;

class procedure TMain.Fill_NewListForDistinctValues(const AllIntegers: TIntegerList; const IntegerListList:
    TIntegerListList);
type
  TIntegerListDictionary = TDictionary<Integer, TIntegerList>;
var
  IntegerListDictionary: TIntegerListDictionary;
  IntegerList: TIntegerList;
  Value: Integer;
begin
  IntegerListDictionary := TIntegerListDictionary.Create();
  for Value in AllIntegers do
  begin
    if IntegerListDictionary.ContainsKey(Value) then
      IntegerList := IntegerListDictionary[Value]
    else
    begin
      IntegerList := AddNewIntegerList(IntegerListList);
      IntegerListDictionary.Add(Value, IntegerList);
    end;
    IntegerList.Add(Value);
  end;
end;

class procedure TMain.Free(const IntegerListList: TIntegerListList);
var
  IntegerList: TIntegerList;
begin
  for IntegerList in IntegerListList do
    IntegerList.Free;
  IntegerListList.Free;
end;

class procedure TMain.Print(const IntegerList: TIntegerList);
var
  Value: Integer;
  First: Boolean;
begin
  First := True;
  for Value in IntegerList do
  begin
    if not First then
      Write(', ');
    Write(Value);
    First := False;
  end;
  Writeln;
end;

class procedure TMain.Print(const IntegerListList: TIntegerListList);
var
  IntegerList: TIntegerList;
begin
  for IntegerList in IntegerListList do
    Print(IntegerList);
  Writeln;
end;

class procedure TMain.Run;
var
  AllIntegers: TIntegerList;
  IntegerListList: TIntegerListList;
begin
  AllIntegers := TIntegerList.Create();
  try
    AddValues(AllIntegers);
    Print(AllIntegers);

    IntegerListList := TIntegerListList.Create();
    try
      Fill_NewListForEachValueChange(AllIntegers, IntegerListList);
      Print(IntegerListList);
    finally
      Free(IntegerListList);
    end;

    AddValues(AllIntegers);
    Print(AllIntegers);

    IntegerListList := TIntegerListList.Create();
    try
      Fill_NewListForEachValueChange(AllIntegers, IntegerListList);
      Print(IntegerListList);
    finally
      Free(IntegerListList);
    end;

    Print(AllIntegers);

    IntegerListList := TIntegerListList.Create();
    try
      Fill_NewListForDistinctValues(AllIntegers, IntegerListList);
      Print(IntegerListList);
    finally
      Free(IntegerListList);
    end;
  finally
    AllIntegers.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    TMain.Run();
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: I think some outline of the algorithm would help. Just saying "use a set of loops" is perhaps not specific enough.

Comment: Will do as soon as I'm home on a machine that has generics.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this example Jeroen, it helps a lot. Since my original post I had made a similar function using TDictionary (as per David's suggestion) but your example expands on it with very useful extras. I have some questions regarding freeing memory but I think it's more appropriate to post a separate question so I can explain the scenarios in detail.